# cmd // stop service ONLY if it's running, otherwise declare a variable

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, services, windows-services

I'd like to make a short script which:

1. Checks if specified services are running.
2. If they do then they should be stopped (otherwise declare variable/s for the last point).
3. Then there will be some code I've already created.
4. Previously stopped services should be started again (so I don't want to start all of them).

---

I'm trying to determine if a service is running *(service example: bits)*

`sc query bits | findstr "RUNNING"` // if the service *bits* is running the output is:

`STATE              : 4  RUNNING`

I can stop/start the service with `net stop bits`/`net start bits`.

#### But how can I avoid starting services which shouldn't be started?

(I mean they were not running at the early). **Use 'tokens' somehow?**

What I made so far is:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %s in ('sc query ^| find "SERVICE_NAME" ^| FIND /i "Bits"') do @echo %s` and/or `for /f "tokens=2" %s in ('sc query state^= inactive ^| find "SERVICE_NAME" ^| find /i "Bits"') do @echo %s
```

Which can return a value ("BITS" or NUL), so I guess I need to assign a variable to it now for the future use

Comment: This is *not* a script writing service, but if you write a script, you can get help here -- show your work. This *might* help *tasklist* to see if a service or application is running. See use of IF in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/batch-script-how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script/.

Comment: There's no problem with starting an already started service - the command will just fail.